# how to get contacts list from google glass using GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api, google-contacts-api

I'm implement Google Glass app.

I want to get contacts list from google glass using GDK.

I already tried contacts Api v3 (ContactsService)

but i failed because -

i can't scrolling & tapping(click) pop-up (OK Button) after glass update XE16

-> run to android phone is ok.

i tried
mirror api. device OAuth.... -> no example.. i don't know how...

if you have sample code, As it is also upload. Would you? I'd appreciate that.

here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private Account[] accounts;
    private AccountManager mManager;
    private ContactsService mService;
    private URL feedUrl;
    private final String url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";
    private final String ACCOUNTS_TYPE = "com.google";
    private final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "cp";
    private String mToken;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        mManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        accounts = mManager.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNTS_TYPE);

        Log.d("account", ""+accounts[0]);

        mManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>()
        {
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future)
            {
                try
                {
                    mToken = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    GetTask task = new GetTask();
                    task.execute(mToken);
                }

                catch (OperationCanceledException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (AuthenticatorException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }

    public void createService(String token) throws IOException, ServiceException
    {
        mService = new ContactsService("contacts_list");
        mService.setUserToken(token);

        feedUrl = new URL(url);

        ContactFeed resultFeed = (ContactFeed)mService.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
        for (ContactEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) getContacts(entry);
    }

    private class GetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {
                String token = "";

                if(params != null)
                {
                    for(String s : params) token += s;
                }

                createService(token);
            }

            catch (ServiceException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public void getContacts(ContactEntry entry) throws ServiceException, IOException
    {
        if (entry.hasName())
        {
            Name name = entry.getName();

            if (name.hasFullName())
            {
                String fullName = name.getFullName().getValue();
                Log.d("name", fullName);
            }
    }

        else Log.d("name", "no name");

        if (entry.hasPhoneNumbers())
        {
            for (PhoneNumber phone : entry.getPhoneNumbers())
            {
                String phoneNum = phone.getPhoneNumber();
                Log.d("phone", phoneNum);
            }
        }

        else Log.d("phone", "no phone");

    }
}
```

Comment: Your English is a little rough. What do you mean by "I can't scrolling and tapping ... after XE16"? I have created lists of views and been able to scroll through them just fine. I can also set the onKeyDown callback and have it create a new activity or what not when the card is tapped on.